# Regarding hydrolysis of ATP in ABC transporter

Tags: membrane-transport

So, I was going through this lecture about ABC transporter and one point about it confused me. ABC transporter is not the same as an ATPase but let's take an example of Cystic Fibrosis Transmembrane Regulator. In it 2 molecules of ATP bind with the channel and then they undergo hydrolysis in order for Chloride ion movement to occur. So,if hydrolysis is occurring when ATP was bound to the channel then shouldn't it also function as an ATPase or is it so that it is binding and the channel isn't doing the function of hydrolysis, some other molecule is and it is just using that energy.

Comment: "ABC transporter is not an ATPase" - according to whom?

Comment: They told me that an ABC transporter is not the same thing as an ATPase

Comment: Can you provide a quote? "ABC transporter is not the same thing as an ATPase" is true just like "an automobile is not the same thing as a vehicle" is true. "ABC transporter is not an ATPase" is false in general, though may be true for a *specific* ABC family member.

Comment: See on the topmost of lecture where they write what topic they are teaching, they wrote that ABC transporters are not ATPases but the teacher that was doing lecture said that an ABC transporter is not the same thing as an ATPase. Well by the way can you tell me the difference between the two statements as they seem kinda same to me.

Comment: Also, should I edit the question's statement to make it better

Comment: @Bryan Krause, I have edited the question so that it'll be more meaningful. But can you please explain that why despite of the fact that hydrolysis is occurring in the channel, it is not the same as an ATPase. Also, why one shouldn't say directly that it is not an ATPase and use not the same thing as ATPase.

Comment: I'm guessing your instructor is referring to a family of ATPases rather than functional ATPase activity. But without some sort of quote or actual evidence I'm always hesitant to provide guidance that can mislead a student when there is confusion between what an instructor says and what a student hears.

Comment: @Bryan Krause, yes you are right. The teacher was talking about pumps, Na-K ATPase pump to be specific. But as far as evidence goes, I gave you exactly what teacher had said and I'm confident coz I even used subtitles for that video. The teacher had said what you are quoting but I'm confused that despite of the fact that ATP hydrolysis is occurring, why we cannot refer it to as an ATPase.